# Import javax in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in eclipse and I would like to use JFrame, but I dont have the javax package. I have the jar file, but I tried EVERYTHING and it doesnt work. I tried putting it in reference libraries and re-installing eclipse. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don't know. How would i know if its set up correctly?

Comment: https://ibb.co/cwkBsJv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet those errors say `The package java.awt is not accessible` and `The type javax.swing.JFrame is not accessible`.

You need to add `requires java.desktop;` to your `module-info.java` file.

Comment: I can accept your answer in 7 minutes, sorry for the wait. Its just what the website says.

Comment: @TristanRemus Yeah, standard 15 minute wait, to give others a chance to come up with a better answer (as if they could ).

Comment: also, do you know what the red "!" is next to my JAVA class?

Comment: @TristanRemus It means there are errors in the file. Helpful to guide you to the files with errors, so you can open them and see the actual errors. You could also just click on the `Problems` view, in the lower right pane.

Comment: ok thank you. I didnt realize i had such a simple problem. Have a good day! ... or night!

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by just deleting the "module-info.java" file. Simple like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that a fix. Removing the file will result in running the code in the unnamed module.